# Limit with radicals, $\cos$, $\ln$ and powers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-writing

$\underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}\lim{\frac{\sqrt[6]{1-\cos{\frac{1}{x^3}}}\Big(2^{-\frac{1}{x}}\;-\;3^{-\frac{1}{x}}\Big)}{\ln(x-1)^{\frac{1}{x}}-\ln{x^{\frac{1}{x}}}}}=\underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}\lim{\frac{\sqrt[6]{1-\cos{\frac{1}{x^3}}}\Big(2^{-\frac{1}{x}}\;-\;3^{-\frac{1}{x}}\Big)}{\ln(\frac{x-1}{x})^{\frac{1}{x}}}}=\underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}\lim{\frac{\sqrt[6]{1-\cos{\frac{1}{x^3}}}\Big(\frac{\sqrt[x]{3}-\sqrt[x]{2}}{\sqrt[x]{6}}\Big)}{\frac{1}{x}\ln{\Big(1-\frac{1}{x}\Big)}}}=0$

My answer is rather imprecise:$$\underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}\lim{\cos{\frac{1}{x^3}}}=1\implies\underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}\lim{\sqrt[6]{1-\cos{\frac{1}{x^3}}}}=0$$
$$\underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}\lim{\frac{\sqrt[x]{3}-\sqrt[x]{2}}{\sqrt[x]{6}}}=0?$$
I am aware of the mistake I have made by writting $0$ for an undefined term.
$$\underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}\lim{\Big(1-\frac{1}{x^3}\Big)}=1\implies \ln{\Big(1-\frac{1}{x}\Big)}<0\implies\underset{x\rightarrow +\infty}\lim{\Bigg(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x}\ln{\Big(1-\frac{1}{x}\Big)}}\Bigg)=-\infty}$$
The limit of the denumerator is $0$ $\&$ the limit of the whole expression is $0$.
How can I prove this concisely?

Comment: See [wolframalpha's answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+%282%5E%28-1%2Fx%29-3%5E%28-1%2Fx%29%29*%281-cos%281%2Fx%5E3%29%29%5E%281%2F6%29*x%2Fln%281-1%2Fx%29+as+x-%3Einfinity) if I typed in correctly. Maybe you should do Taylor series of f(1/x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion is wrong since we find an indeterminate form $\frac 0 0$ and we can't conclude that the limit is zero.

Indeed we have that by standard limits

$$\sqrt[6]{1-\cos{\frac{1}{x^3}}} = \frac1{x\sqrt[6]2}+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$$

$$2^{-\frac{1}{x}}\;-\;3^{-\frac{1}{x}} = \frac1x\log \frac32+O\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)$$

therefore

$${\frac{\sqrt[6]{1-\cos{\frac{1}{x^3}}}\Big(2^{-\frac{1}{x}}\;-\;3^{-\frac{1}{x}}\Big)}{\ln(x-1)^{\frac{1}{x}}-\ln{x^{\frac{1}{x}}}}}= \frac{\frac1{x^2}\left(\frac1{\sqrt[6]2}+O\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right)\left( \log \frac32+O\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right)}{{\frac{1}{x}\ln{\Big(1-\frac{1}{x}\Big)}}}=$$

$$= \frac{\left(\frac1{\sqrt[6]2}+O\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right)\left( \log \frac32+O\left(\frac1{x}\right)\right)}{\frac{\ln{\Big(1-\frac{1}{x}\Big)}}{\frac1x}}\to -\frac1{\sqrt[6]2}\log \frac32$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!

Comment: @VerkhotsevaKatya You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 2):

Let's rewrite the thing to $$L=\lim\limits_{x\to+0}\frac{\left( 1-\cos x^3\right)^\frac16\left(2^{-x}-3^{-x}\right)}{x\ln(1-x)}$$
Each of the things to first order will suffice, so let's start:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1\Rightarrow
\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\ln a,$$
$$1-\cos(x^3)=2sin^2\left(\frac{x^3}{2}\right), 
\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1\Rightarrow
\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{2sin^2\left(\frac{x^3}{2}\right)}{\left(\frac{x^3}{2}\right)^2}=2,$$
[$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=1$$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%28x-%3E0%29+log%281+%2B+x%29%2Fx)
Should I do the rest? )

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to finish it on my own if possible!

Comment: Let me know if you don't, there's really not much left)

Answer (score 1):

Examine the expression you have,

$$\underset{x\rightarrow \infty}\lim{\frac{\sqrt[6]{1-\cos{\frac{1}{x^3}}}\Big(\frac{\sqrt[x]{3}-\sqrt[x]{2}}{\sqrt[x]{6}}\Big)}{\frac{1}{x}\ln{\Big(1-\frac{1}{x}\Big)}}}$$

Note that in the limit $x\rightarrow \infty$,

$$ \sqrt[6]{1-\cos\frac 1{x^3}} \rightarrow
\sqrt[6]{1-(1-\frac12 \frac 1{x^6})}
=\frac1{\sqrt[6]2}\frac1x$$

$$\frac{3^{\frac1x}-2^{\frac1x}}{6^{\frac1x}}
\rightarrow (1+\ln3 \frac1x)-( 1+\ln2 \frac1x)= \ln\frac32\frac1x$$

$$\frac1x \ln(1-\frac1x) \rightarrow - \frac1{x^2}$$

Thus, the limiting value is

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac {\left( \frac1{\sqrt[6]2}\frac1x\right) \left(  \ln\frac32\frac1x\right)}{-\frac1{x^2}}
=- \frac1{\sqrt[6]2}\ln\frac32$$

Comment: Sorry but that notation $\frac1x \ln(1-\frac1x) \rightarrow - \frac1{x^2}$ is rwally bad, maybe it would be better $\frac1x \ln(1-\frac1x) \sim - \frac1{x^2}$ or $\approx$ if we are making a rough estimation.